# What is the maximum size in MB for WinRT isolated storage?

Tags: windows-runtime

In Windows Phone 7, the maximum size for isolated storage was 90 MB.  What is the size for isolated storage for Windows Runtime applications?

Comment: Isolated storage is not implemented in WinRT.  There's ApplicationData.RoamingStorageQuota but that's not available on Phone 8.

Comment: Actually I was wrong.  The maximum memory for a Windows Phone 7 application is 90MB.  The isolated storage size is 2GB.  So what is the ApplicationData.RoamingStorageQuota per application in WinRT?  Is it 2GB as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only disk is the limit for LocalSettings/Folder

100k is the limit for RoamingSettings/Folder

[Quickstart: Local application data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh700361%28v=win.10%29.aspx)